# JTable sorting not working with Java 1.6

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablerowsorter, rowsorter

I have a legacy swing application where the JTable sorting works correctly with Java 1.5 but not with Java 1.6. Could someone provide me hints as to what could be different between the two versions?

The sorting is handled by a mouse click event handler. Here is the snippet of the code.

```
 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
  {
    if ((e.getModifiers() & InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK) != 0) 
    {
      JTableHeader header = (JTableHeader) e.getSource();
      JTable table = header.getTable();
      int col = table.columnAtPoint(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()));
      int colModel = table.convertColumnIndexToModel(col);
      TableSorter model = (TableSorter)table.getModel(); // the table model also implements sorting.

      boolean order;

      if (model.getSortedColumn() == colModel) 
      {
        order = ! model.getCurrentOrder();
      }
      else 
      {
        order = true;
      }

      model.sortByColumn(colModel, order);

      header.repaint();
      table.repaint();
    }

  }
```

there are no exceptions produced. I hv tried running with jdb. The getValueAt(int, int) function returns the proper value with both java 1.5 and java 1.6 after sorting.

Comment: any exception or error log ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi no exceptions thrown. I hv added some more details in the post.

Comment: What's the mouse listener registered to?

Comment: @MadProgrammer its registered to JTableHeader.addMouseListener

Comment: It's possible that the UI delegate is taking control and consuming the mouse events as this is how it works by default (at least under Java 6 anyway).  The `TableHeader` will now change the sort order of the column you click on.